# WebApi 2.1 in IIS Hosting - OWIN

Tags: owin, asp.net-web-api2, katana

I started by creating a console app and running as a self host OWIN app. Installed Web API and all works fine.

Now I installed the SystemWeb nuget package, change the type of app to "class library", change output folder to "bin\" only.

When I run the application using IIS Express, first time I load the app, I receive an exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I realized that the System.Web.Http.Owin is referencing the Microsoft.Owin -V 2.0.2.0.

In the App.config the following exists:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Despite the above, still getting the same exception. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this. Copy the app.config and rename it to web.config. This will enable IIS/IIS Express to use the necessary binding redirects.

Comment: Nothing solved the problem! I had to start with an Empty Website in VS 2013, remove all System.Web references, start with Self-host, then move to IIS, it all works! Starting with a Console app with Self Host then move to IIS, fails to work!

Comment: Hmm,  not sure what the problem was for you then,  since the above definitely worked for me. At least your going now!

Comment: Yeah, I want to start from a console, but for some reasons, didnt work. Thanks in all cases

Comment: @Bill, some xmlns attributes may cause problems: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667286/Assembly-Redirection-Doesn-sharp-t-work-in-web-c

Answer (score 0):

From the References list, set the Owin DLL to be "Copied Always" on compile.

Comment: Tried an app with that DLL, I didn't need all those lines in Web.config. Just had the OWIN dll in the BIN folder. It just worked. Try it...

Comment: Create a console app, install SelfHost nuget package, then install WebAPI nuget package, then install SystemWeb package, and try to run the app from iis express.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the binding redirect is doing anything for you since the version you referenced (2.0.2.0) isn't in the binding redirect.

You can use the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) tool to debug type load exceptions.